# Distance between two points above horizon

Tags: geometry

I know that the distance to the horizon is proportional to the square of the height of the person, $d=k\sqrt{h}$.
If I'm given that a person is $1.8$ metres tall and sees $4.8$ kilometres out to sea, $k$ is $3577$. I can then pretty easily work out how far an $x$ meter tall person can see.  However, if the $1.8$ metre tall person can just barely see the top of a ten metre mast above the horizon, how far away is the boat? How would I go about solving this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you can barely see it, then there's a spot on the Earth that is on the horizon for you *and* for the boat: add the horizon distances for both yourself and the boat's mast.

[image: a diagram of the scenario: a circle with a tangent supported by two short lines]

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Why does that work though?  I'm trying to get my head around the geometry of it?

Comment: I've added a diagram that should explain the scenario

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon#Distance_to_the_horizon By the way, wikipedia's section on this problem is really, really nice.  I'm especially pleased with the comparison of air distance, ground distance, and approximate distance from the simplified formula.  I had no idea it was that close for that long!

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much for your help.  That clears it up!