# Distance of partially visible objects over the horizon?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

I want to solve [Distance between two points above horizon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3125880/distance-between-two-points-above-horizon) for objects that are partially visible rather than only just? Is my logic and the calculations below correct?

If I stick my arm (75cm) out and the top $x$ meters of a 1000m tower looks 3cm tall, how far away is it?

On a flat plane, or approximately over short distances I can use similar triangles:

$$\frac{3cm}{75cm} = \frac{1000m}{x}$$

Where $x = 25km$ is the distance to my tower when full visible.

And the distance to my tower, given my height, when it is just barely visible is given by:

$$x = 3.57*(\sqrt{1.78}+\sqrt{1000}) = 117km$$

So I tried combining the two, and replacing the 1000m height with 1000-x, where x is the amount visible.

$$\frac{3}{75} = \frac{x}{3.57*(\sqrt{1.78}+\sqrt{1000-x})}$$

Which gives $x = 0.00433294km = 4.33m$.

But something about that doesn't seem right to me?

Here is a [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%2F75+%3D+x%2F%283.57*%28sqrt%281.78%29%2Bsqrt%281000-x%29%29%2F1000%29) to my calculations on Wolfram Alpha. If I reverse the equation:

$$\frac{y}{75} = \frac{200}{3.57*(\sqrt{1.78}+\sqrt{1000-200})}$$

Which is to ask, how tall does it look, when I can only see the top 200 meters. The answer that's spat out is ~19 m, which seems excessively tall given that $3.57*(\sqrt{1.78}+\sqrt{1000-200})$ is ~100km away?

To assist with understanding the scenario, I've modified the diagram from the linked question:

[image: diagram of observer, earth and object visible over the horizon. Constructions lines extend from the observer, tangent to the earth that intersect a point some distance from the top of the observed object. A line also extends observer to the top of the object]

Have I calculated this right?

Comment: Hi! I had a similarish question before [see here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/610996/maximum-distance-between-two-towers-for-space-wave-propogations) it may help.

Comment: @Buraian that's more or less a cross-site duplicate of the question I linked in the opening paragraph: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3125880/distance-between-two-points-above-horizon

Comment: Looking at that diagram it's clear I have something wrong, but I'm not sure how significant an error it is...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is sound, but you're suffering due to not keeping careful track of units. Taking your final cross-check equation for the quantity $y$, which is a good idea for a cross-check: on the left hand side $y$ and the denominator 75 are in centimeters, while on the right hand side the numerator is in meters while the denominator is in kilometers. If you'll calculate more carefully, you'll find that $y \approx 0.142 cm$:
$$
\frac{y}{75cm} = \frac{200m}{3.57 km \times \sqrt{(1000m-200m)/1m}}
$$

For your original problem, work to rewrite the equation with units in the same fashion, and you'll get a much more reasonable answer.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I thought my calculation on wolfram alpha was correct. I'll have to go back and check. Also I'm not sure where $1m$ comes from is that meant to be 1000?EDIT:  AHHH I was dividing the denominator, not the numerator!

Comment: Yep, you caught it. The $/1m$, by the way, is me writing down the correct units for the calculation in the denominator. Alternatively I could have written $3.57 km \, m^{-1/2} \sqrt{1000m-200m}$.